# Generate comments in bulk for TypeScript files

Tags: typescript, comments

I am trying to generate comments (in JavaDoc style `/*** .. */`) in the front part for an application (angular .ts files) where they are missing in a project.
For this i would like to generate them for many files at the same time (and for the moment i do not worry if they are just "approximatively" helpfull, the idea is to make some basic comments as a base and slowly convert them to more usefull ones). The only solutions i found, can only to generate them one by one (like "Document This" in VSCode).
Is there any bulk-comment-generating tools out there?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you give some more details like: Do you want to add a comment at the beginning of each file only or for each class or function in each file? Also it could be helpful to tell us which operating system you use. And from your question I assume this is a one-time job (i.e. you don't want auto-generation for files added in the future).

Comment: OS windows, 
at all apropriate places:
before each class, and each function. I would prefere add them to already existing ones, the new ones should be commented manualy (try to adapt project to new 100% documentation requirements)